# Getting the current routeName in react navigation

Tags: react-native, routes, navigation, state

I want to get the name of the current routeName in react navigator. I came across three solutions:

```
 1. const { routeName } = navigation.state.routes[navigation.state.index];

 2. this.props.navigation.state.RouteName

 3. const route = navigationState.routes[navigationState.index];
```

The first one seems to work fine. For the second one, I am not sure  how to use it. The third option (as given in official documentation), generates the error with 
`ReferenceError: navigationState is undefined`.

Please help me out in which is the correct way to find the name of the active screen while navigation.

Answer (score 2):

```
function getActiveRouteName(navigationState) {
  if (!navigationState) {
    return null
  }
  const route = navigationState.routes[navigationState.index]
  if (route.routes) {
    return getActiveRouteName(route)
  }
  return route.routeName
}

// Example Usage
const currentScreen = getActiveRouteName(this.props.router);
if (currentScreen === 'Login') {
   // do something
}
```

Comment: can you please explain a bit?

Comment: As you can see, the route looks like `routes(an Array) + index(a number)` inside, so you just need to open it by `routes[index]`(we call it route A), if you find route A still looks like `routes(an Array) + index(a number)` inside, you need to open it again and again, until you find the deepest route which you need. The deepest route doesn't has routes as its property.